How to make DataGrid column background transparent?
I want to have a column in my DataGrid with a transparent background in my WPF application. The header and the cells themselves need to be transparent, but not the content inside of it, which will be a button.
I see RowBackground exists, but no parameter for a column.

Assuming this is C# in Windows Forms, it requires a CellPainting function to colour the grid transparent and then replace the data. All done in the standard .NET libraries. Here's an example:

Here is the function:
` private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == -1)
     {
         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent), e.CellBounds);
         e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
         e.Handled = true;
     }
     else if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
     {

         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent), e.CellBounds);
         e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
         e.Handled = true;
     }
 }`

With this line then placed after initializing the grid: dataGridView1.CellPainting += DataGridView1_CellPainting;

OP tagged the question as WPF related. I think "assuming it is Windows Forms" is incorrect.

Ye, its in wpf, sorry for not clarifiying it, gonna edit the question.

Sorry its my fault, I didn't notice the tag I thought I was filtering by WinForms. Does the logic still work similarly I'm not familiar.

WPF's DataGrid Columns want you to edit Column's templates CellStyle. You'll want to put the cell style in a resource dictionary or in the respective xaml's resources. I didn't make a style for the button but you could do the same thing. Using this also means you can't auto generate the columns without doing a lot so you'll need to create the DataGrid columns according to your item source in the data context.
<Style 
    x:Key="ExampleDataGridCellStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
<Style 
    x:Key="TransparentHeaderStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>

<DataGrid
  ItemSource="{Binding YourCoolCollection}"
  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource TransparentHeaderStyle}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn
        CellStyle="{StaticResource ExampleDataGridCellStyle}">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="0">
                    YourButton
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Header="Foo"
            Binding="{Binding Bar}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>

